# Alternative to creating custom menu with onOpen trigger in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, quota

Google allows a maximum of 20 triggers per user/script. I have over 20 reports, and originally wanted to have one spreadsheet per report, each with a custom menu that allows the user to refresh the report.

The only way that I know how to reveal the custom menu is via an `onOpen` trigger. Because I have over 20 spreadsheets and Google's trigger number limit is 20, I can't create an `onOpen` trigger for each spreadsheet to create the custom menu.

Is there an alternative way to render a custom menu or something of that ilk without triggers? Are my only alternatives to create a button in each spreadsheet and assign a script to it or create fewer spreadsheets with many sheets in each spreadsheet?

Comment: First a new spreadsheet per report is a bad idea. Use a single spreadsheet and provide data via a web app. Secondly, it's 20 per user per script. That would mean 1 script(spreadsheet) can have 20 triggers per user.